# The additions to finally?

Tags: java

help make only can write the code, and then I'm a newbie) Here is a piece of code:

```
if(myName.equals(name)){
    BufferedReader br = null;
    try{
        File file =  new File("C:\\Users\\vany\\Desktop\\test\\" + list[i]);
        br =  new BufferedReader(new InputStreamReader(
        new FileInputStream(file), "UTF8"));

        PrintWriter wr =   response.getWriter();
        wr.print("<html>");
        wr.print("<head>");
        wr.print("<title>HelloWorld</title>");
        wr.print("<body>");
        wr.write("<div>");
        wr.write(br.readLine());

        wr.write(br.readLine());//link1
        wr.write("</div>");
        wr.write("<hr>");
        wr.print("</body>");
        wr.print("</html>");
        wr.close();
    }
    catch(XException e){
    }
```

But to leave just catch - bad thing to add to it?

```
 catch(XException e){

}
```

Comment: What?? I'm sorry, but I don't even know what you're asking here. Could you try rephrasing your question?

Comment: If you got nothing to put in `finally`, why not use a `try...catch`? Try something and catch the exception

Comment: @JoachimSauer I think he means that he needs to use the `try` block but is a bad thing to leave the `finally` block empty. Hence, he can use a `try...catch` block instead

Answer (score 5, accepted):

If you use a `try/finally` statement with no code in the `finally` block, that's equivalent to not using `try/finally` at all.

In this case, your `finally` block *should* contain code to close the writer and the reader even if an exception is thrown.

If you're using Java 7, you can use a [try-with-resources statement](http://docs.oracle.com/javase/tutorial/essential/exceptions/tryResourceClose.html) to do this more simply.

Answer (score 1):

If you don't need `finally` you can remove it (as well as the `try`)

Answer (score 1):

The basic structure of try, catch and finally is as follows

```
try{
...
}catch(XException e){
...
}finally{
...
}
```

If you write try then you must have to catch the exception or finally block.

If you have placed try then you must have to place either catch or finally.

Comment: actually, catch is not mandatory as well, your try should either have a catch or finally

Comment: @GanGnaMStYleOverFlowErroR And since Java 7 neither is required if it is a try-with-resources.

Comment: @MarkRotteveel yeah, cux i guess try-with-resourse's main objective is to make sure that the resources are closed. is it right ?? i am not sure though :)